# can elasticsearch search MS-access?

Tags: ms-access, elasticsearch

I am trying to built a search on MS Access using elastic search but did not find any info related to it on the website or google searches. IS anyone aware if MS-Access can be searched using elastic search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to export the data FROM MS Access INTO elasticsearch.

Elasticsearch doesn't 'search' other databases, it searches it's own. How you get the data from your original data source (whatever it is) into elasticsearch is up to you.

Comment: Yes. I do get that. I meant to ask How do I export data from MS-Access into elasticsearch?

Comment: One solution that I am thinking about is to export it to SQL first and then to elastic but I am wondering if there is way to do it directly..

Comment: with .net this would be easy. read the data from access using ADO.net. Iterate over each row and POST to elastic search using the .net elastic search wrapper https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net

Comment: looks like this should work.. I will try this and get back to you.. and then accept the answer.. thanks..

Comment: Hey Alex I am on a holiday(long weekend u see)  will be joining back work on monday will try it by then..

Comment: it worked like a charm. very simple and straight forward. thanks @alex